# See all rows and download the result to csv in pgAdmin4

Tags: export-to-csv, pgadmin-4

I have data 66596470 which i got from calculation in query not from table. but in pgAdmin4 I can only see 1000 of 66596470. How can I see all rows or download them to csv? Thank you...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not PostgreSQL you are talking about, but a GUI client that limits the number of result rows. You can probably configure the unnamed tool to display more than 1000 rows, but if you tried to actually *see* all 66 million rows, that would take a lot of time, both for the client software and you as a reader, and the client would probably go out of memory.

If you want to *retrieve* (rather than see) the complete result set, use `psql`'s `\copy` command to write the result set to a file. FOr example:

```
\copy (SELECT ...) TO 'filename' (FORMAT 'csv')
```

Comment: hiii thank you so much, but i got wrong message ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"

Comment: Then you are not using `psql`.